# How to use Orientation Sensor in AndEngine

Tags: android, orientation, andengine

I'm developing a game with AndEngine. I want to draw a sprite depending on current azimuth of my devices. How can I do it?
sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, you need to:

- have your class derived from ***BaseGameActivity*** and implement the ***IOrientationListener*** interface (i.e. overridding the ***onOrientationChanged()*** method)
- toward the end of the intialization process, invoke, the mEngine's ***enableOrientationSensor()***
- you'll receive the orientation data from the OrientatonData parameter of the ***onOrientationChanged()***, you'll typically use the `getRoll()`, but depending on the complexity of your game's gestures, the `getPitch()` and `getYaw` would give you the other directions.
- if needed you could alter the Orientation sensor's settings as with other input sensors (e.g. make it refresh more or less frequently, with more or less precision etc.)

Tentatively, the [**AugmentedRealityHorizonExample**](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/AugmentedRealityHorizonExample.java?r=9362dff04f9e65f6aecbe2501cc65899f615189c) source code shows you how this is all put together, although this example may be a bit more complicated than your needs, as it uses a `BaseAugmentedRealityGameActivity`.